# Forking child processes on file system events in perl

Tags: perl, filesystems, fork, inotify

I have a daemon process written in Perl that uses Inotify2 to watch directories for incoming files. On arrival of each file, the daemon will fork a child process. Now, it seems too many files are arriving at the same time (hence too many forks), because I got this error in my log file:

```
Cannot allocate memory at notifyd.pl line ...
```

which is the result of fork().

Basically I have the following code:

```
    my $inotify = new Linux::Inotify2() or die($!);

    foreach my $k (@PATHS) {
        $inotify->watch($k,
IN_MOVE_SELF|IN_DELETE_SELF|IN_CLOSE_WRITE, \&watcher) or die($!);
    }

    $inotify->blocking(1) or die($!);

    for(;;) {
        $inotify->poll() or die($!);
    }
```

with the watcher function doing fork and then execv:

```
sub watcher {
        my $e = shift;
        my $pid = fork();
        if(!defined $pid) {
            print "[ERROR]", $!;
        }
        elsif($pid == 0) {
            my @args = ($e->fullname, $e->mask);
            exec($childprocess, @args) or die($!);
        }
}
```

I cannot afford to miss events by not forking a process.

Does anyone have suggestions how I can improve this and make sure fork will not fail?

---

Edit: it seems like the child processes were becoming zombies once they exited since the daemon would not respond to SIGCHLD. So a lot of zombie child processes could have been the reason why fork() failed. The daemon now does    `$SIG{CHLD} = 'IGNORE';` before forking.

Comment: If you have a lot of file changes it is pretty easy to exhaust resources and depending on your use case it is a vector for dos attacks. You should handle those events with one of the event loops on cpan. A good starting point might be looking at AnyEvent.

Comment: Are you sure fork() is failing?  The error message you (partially) present looks like it came from `die` or `warn`, but the code you show would not produce that output if fork failed (that is, if `$pid` were undefined).

Comment: Yes, the message came from this part of the code:
if(!defined $pid) { print "[ERROR]", $!; }

Comment: Er, but we don't see the token "[Error]", and neither `$!` nor `print` normally append "at _script_ line _whatever_".  The error you show, in the form you show it, did not come from that line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solve the problem by adding another layer of indirection.

When you receive an event, put the file name into a [job queue](http://enwp.org/Job_queue). The queue starts a new job processing the file when resources are reasonable free; this scheme guarantees that the event will eventually be acted upon, just not all of them immediately.

Comment: Thanks, I need to look into the possible ways of implementing it. The thing is I wouldn't really want to have another process just for dealing with the queue.

Answer (score 2):

Use a more robust background process manager like [`Forks::Super`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Forks%3a%3aSuper)

This setup, for example, will have up to 10 forks running at a time. New requests that come in when all 10 forks are busy will be put on a queue. Jobs in the queue will be run as other background processes complete and resources become available.

```
use Forks::Super  MAX_PROC => 10, ON_BUSY => 'queue';

...

sub watcher {
    my $e = shift;
    fork {
       sub => sub {
           my @args = ($e->fullname, $e->mask);
           exec($childprocess, @args) or die($!);
       }
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That looks good, except I might not be able to have that module installed, so I'll have to implement something similar by myself.